# Salesforce Apex Callouts to Marketing Cloud

Tags: salesforce, apex, exacttarget

I need to make an Apex Callout to Marketing Cloud when a Lead is created in Salesforce that matches certain criteria.  I would like to use this MC Rest API - https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:Autoemail/send. The issue then is that I first need to authenticate with MC to get an Access Token to pass when making the above API call.  Does anyone have a good way to persist the Access Token in a Salesforce org?  I'm thinking of storing it in a Custom Setting and only updating it when an Apex callout goes to use it and sees that it's nearly 60 minutes old. Is anyone doing something similar?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you know that access token to external service can be expired and should be updated sometimes automatically, the better approach is which you choose - custom setting (or custom object for storing it).

If this token can be hardcoded one time and it will not be changed for a long period, you can checkout [Authentication Settings for External Systems](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=external_authentication.htm&type=0) functionality.

Comment: Thanks Hleb, it looks like Marketing Cloud Access Tokens always expire in 60 minutes.  Is anybody out there using this approach already to integrate with MC?

Comment: @Kevinmurray unfortunately, I didn't work with Marketing Cloud, but I used approach with custom settings for integration with another third-party service and this completely satisfied our needs.